# tree code giving wrong output. logic error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, algorithm

https://jsfiddle.net/mikeyounes/4ndtmaun/1/
https://api.myjson.com/bins/5a9vo

i am using an html and jquery code to take json nested objects and output them as a tree. its working. the problem is that the nodes arent coming out in their right place. for example, a node is coming out as a child instead of being a sibling. i believe the error is in this function. i can give u the whole code and the json but when im posting it im not getting any help, theyre too long maybe. been stuck for long on this, would be appreciated if u checked it out.

```
function traverse(node, o) {
    for (var i in o) {
        if(i == "__text" || i == "_href") {
            continue;
        }

        if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
            if(o[i].__text) {

                var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
                var node=$('<li>').appendTo(ul)

                if(o[i]._href) {
                    var n = $("<span>").appendTo(node)
                    $(n).text(o[i].__text).attr("href", o[i]._href)
                } else {
                    $(node).text(o[i].__text)
                }
            }
        } traverse(node,o[i]);
    } else {
        var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)
        if(o[i].__text) {
            var li = $('<li>' + o[i]._text + '<\/li>').appendTo(ul)

            if(o[i]._href) {
                var n = $("<span>").appendTo(node)
                $(n).text(o[i].__text).attr("href", o[i]._href)
            }
        } else {
            $('<li>' + o[i] + '</li>').appendTo(node)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be a lot easier to help you if you provide a JSFiddle with all required code/data.

Comment: how do i put json file in jsfiddle?

Comment: You could add it as an external resource

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeyounes/4ndtmaun/1/
https://api.myjson.com/bins/5a9vo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code you posted here does not compile. Second of all, it differs from the code you provided via jsfiddle.net and that one does compile. Thus, probably an edit is in order.

Second of all, in the code you provided via jsfiddle.net, move `var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(node)` to right before entering the for loop. This is necessary because all the children of a parent node should be place in the same `ul` tag. I think that should do it.

Also, naming a local variable as one of the function parameters is misleading and can lead to logical errors while implementing an algorithm (see the local variable `node`), though it does seem to have caused problems in this particular case.

Comment: thanks beast. the code is working better now, but still not all the branches are in place. https://jsfiddle.net/mikeyounes/4ndtmaun/4/

Comment: this is the new fiddle, as u can see mainstation 2 is now at its place, but for example control 2 shouldnt be a subscript of control1 in sub2 of main1.
it should be its sibling.
also i didnt get the second part, i cant name it as node?